# Merge classes with OW2 ASM Event based methodology

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I'm trying to come up with the best strategy to merge two classes in one using the ASM Core framework (not the Tree one).

As the ClassReader and ClassVisitor are strictly bound to a single class, how would you do that?

I already searched in the official Docs, but everything is implemented using a ClassNode, which is from the Tree module.

Say we have a base generic interface:

```
public interface CrudDao<T, ID>
{
   T select(final ID id);

   boolean update(final T object);

   boolean insert(final T object);

   boolean delete(final ID id);
}
```

And a concrete generic implementation:

```
public class MyCrudDao<T, ID> implements CrudDao<T, ID>
{
   @Override
   public T select(final ID id) {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public boolean update(final T object) {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public boolean insert(final T object) {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public boolean delete(final ID id) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Now we define an abstract class which extends `CrudDao`, providing additional functionalities or overriding the interface methods, while remaining indifferent to the concrete implementation:

```
public abstract class ConfigurationDao implements CrudDao<Configuration, String>
{
   public List<Configuration> selectAll() {
      ...
   }

   @Override
   public int count() {
      ...
   }
}
```

What I'd like to obtain with ASM is a new concrete class which extends `ConfigurationDao`, which proxy the methods of the `CrudDao` interface to the `MyCrudDao` implementation (if not already overridden, see `count()` above) and which simply copy the abstract class methods.

---

I actually implemented this after Rafael answer, but after a simple benchmark it seems slow compared to what is reported on the ByteBuddy website.

I got around 25-30 ms from the `accept()` call to the `toByteArray()` call (excluded)

Comment: I wouldn’t consider the bound to a single class as “strict”, but this heavily depends on what kind of merging you have in mind. It would be helpful if you could elaborate your intended merging process further.

Comment: @Holger I updated the question with an example

Comment: These classes have incompatible types, `MyCrudDao` is generic allowing to parameterize its implementation of `CrudDao` whereas `ConfigurationDao` invariably implements `CrudDao<Configuration, String>`. How do you want to solve this contradiction? Besides that, when you only want to inject implementation methods, it’s much easier to create another interface with `default` methods and inject that interface into the list of interfaces implemented by `MyCrudDao`.

Comment: @Holger I know, but I'm developing over Java 1.6, so no default methods. Btw what I've done actually works.

Comment: I have no doubt that it works in some context, but it would help if you describe that context. And I hoped that you understand the contradiction that I could write, e.g. `MyCrudDao<BigInteger, Set<Long>> x;` as that’s a valid parameterization of `MyCrudDoa`, still, you’re injecting methods that make only sense if the parameterization is `<Configuration, String>`. It surely work as long as you are only using `MyCrudDao<Configuration, String>`, but if that’s the goal, you shouldn’t declare the class to allow arbitrary type arguments. Understanding your actual use case allows better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to copy unrelated members of two simple classes such as DTOs into the same target class, you can do this by creating one `ClassWriter` and visit both classes that you want to merge:

```
ClassWriter cw = ...
cw.visit(...);
ClassReader cr1 = new ClassReader("foo.Bar"), cr2 = new ClassReader("qux.Baz");
cr1.accept(new MergeGuard(cw), 0);
cr2.accept(new MergeGuard(cw), 0);
cw.visitEnd();
```

In order to avoid that you writer the class file header twice, you have to override the relevant methods in `MergeGuard` that needs to extend `ClassVisitor` to be empty rather then to delegate to the super method which would invoke those methods on your `ClassWriter`.

Comment: They're not totally unrelated, but your example will get me starting!
As soon as I'm home from work I'll update the question with a meaningfull example. It could be useful for others.